# Can't access variable in custom Node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to have a module contain the information for different roles for a game but whenever I try and receive the data from the variables I create, it comes as undefined and/or I get errors saying something similar to saying the variable inside the data doesn't exist (such as the role's name).

I've seen a bunch of tutorials do similar but I can't seem to figure out what I've done wrong.

My index file.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

var RoleList = require('./_modules/RoleList');

var Socket = function() {}
Socket.list = {};

serv.listen(process.env.PORT || 4567);
console.log("Server started.");

var io = require('socket.io')(serv, {});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.id = Math.random();
    Socket.list[socket.id] = socket;
    console.log('Player Connected');

    console.log('Role Name: ' + RoleList.testRole.roleName);

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        delete Socket.list[socket.id];
        console.log('Player Disconnected');
    });
});
```

RoleList Module

```
var Role = function() {
  var self = {};
  var roleName = 'TestingRoleName';
  return self;
}

modules.exports = {
  roleTest: Role
}
```

But upon running the server I get the results.

```
Server started.
Player Connected
T:undefined
```

instead of

```
T:TestingRoleName
```

Is anyone able to help with this? I'd appreciate that so much :D I am likely doing something completely wrong but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

Comment: what is `testRole` in `RoleList.testRole.roleName`? also, `var roleName` won't ever be "accessible" outside `Role` no matter how you code it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This i because `Role` is a `function` not `Object`. You need to call `function` to return `self`. And you should set `roleName` as property of `self`

```
var Role = (function() {
  var self = {};
  self.roleName = 'TestingRoleName';
  return self;
})();
```

Or you can change `Role` to this.This is the way I recommend

```
var Role = {
  roleName:'TestingRoleName'
}
```

Comment: @acksonVirgo accept the answer if you are satisfied.